# JS: deserializing a string with a JSON-like structure

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following string:

`desc: random text string, sender: James, se-status: red, action: runs, target: John, ta-status: blue, status-apply: red, lore: lore ipsum dolor sit amet`

The string is kind of formatted like JSON, just without all the brackets and line breaks and stuff that make it actually useful.

This string always has the categories `desc`, `sender`, `se-status`, `action`, `target`, `ta-status`, `status-apply`, and `lore`. They always appear in that order, but may not always be present, and can carry any string.

The issue is that they can carry literally any string at all - for example, `sender` could carry the string "se-status:" and confuse things. But, that's really unlikely to happen so it shouldn't be an issue really.

It's much more likely that it could contain a comma, which is really useful for breaking methods of extracting the data.

Anyway.

Say I have the aforementioned string in a variable `string`. How would I make it so that `string.sender` === James, and the same for all other categories in the original string?

Comment: Can the string content contain `,`, or is it a safe delimiter?

Comment: Why not just make it real JSON? Where does this text come from?

Comment: The string can contain any character. It's taken from Google Sheets and arrives to me in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var str = "desc: random text string, sender: James, se-status: red, action: runs, target: John, ta-status: blue, status-apply: red, lore: lore ipsum dolor sit amet";

var obj = {};
str.split(',').forEach(function(line) {
     var l = line.split(':');   
   obj[l[0].trim()] = (l[1].trim());   
});

console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

as a function:

```
function myStrToObj(str) {
  var obj = {};
  str.split(',').forEach(function(line) {
     var l = line.split(':');   
     obj[l[0].trim()] = (l[1].trim());   
  });
    return obj;
}
```

**Edit** after explanation from OP

a better parser:

```
function myStrToObj(str) {
    var lastColon = lastComma = -1;
    var key = value = '';
    var obj = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ':') {
            if (lastColon > 0) {
                value = str.substring(lastColon + 1, lastComma).trim();
                obj[key] = value;
                key = str.substring(lastComma + 1, i).trim();
            } else 
                key = str.substring(0, i).trim();
            lastColon = i;
        };

        if (str[i] == ',') 
             lastComma = i;
    };
    value = str.substring(lastColon + 1, str.length).trim();
    obj[key] = value;        
    return obj;
} 

var str = "desc: random text string, sender: James, se-status: red, problem-field: I'm a problem field, I'm a problem field,  action: runs, target: John, ta-status: blue, status-apply: red, lore: lore ipsum dolor sit amet";
var obj = myStrToObj(str);

console.log(obj);
```

I put a JSFiddle with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/gnLk6fdd/14/

**Edit based on Redu's answer**

As I saw Redu's answer I thought it would be much better to create a regex to this. But the problem with his answer is that the field names have to be fixed. I tried to create a regex with capturing groups instead of my answer . My idea was to capture the group, repeat and then go back to last comma or beggining. But my knowlege of regex doesn't get that far.

So I created a question to see if someone can create a regex to this:

[How can I create a regex to parse this string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279565/how-can-i-create-a-regex-to-parse-this-string)

Based on the question I linked above and the corresponding answer by Thomas Ayoub, I saw that if you get Redu's answer and just replace regex by:

```
var r = /([\w-]+):([\w,\s']+)(?:,|$)/g;
```

You can check string without fixed fields.And it's a much better solution than my for loop.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yao97m4s/7/

Comment: This works perfectly, assuming none of the values contain the comma character. Would there be a way to go about solving that? Thank you very much for your time thusly.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to make a more complex parser, that analyse the string char by char looking for : character and then return back to the last comma found to delimit the field. Do you have the option of changing the delimit character from comma to, say, pipe (|) ?

Comment: Sadly not - I'm accessing this data through a Google Sheets URL. The data it provides me with is actually JSON, but the bit that I want to look at isn't... here's the URL https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pbdozFFXCvMo-R77Iez_4BrDcm-TGDUIXndQZbhSs-Y/default/public/basic?alt=json - it may be beneficial to paste this into a beautifier. As you can see, I can change the values themselves, but not the delimiter

Comment: Additionally here's the original sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pbdozFFXCvMo-R77Iez_4BrDcm-TGDUIXndQZbhSs-Y/edit?usp=sharing - I could rename the headers so they're all of equal length, that might make the process easier.

Comment: but this is already a json response... you just load it on a object directly... like var json = output and you're done :)

Comment: If you follow the object path `data.feed.entry[0].content.$t` (where data is the whole JSON document) you'll see that the part of the file that is useful to me is not actually in JSON format, it's just a string that's been dumped in there

Comment: I see... then a more complex parser is the only option. I'll try to do it later or tomorrow ok ? :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd be eternally indebted

Comment: No need for eternal debt. You can keep your socks. You be a free Elf always :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rjjArvzXuc

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. One bug I noticed is that it seems to ignore the last category, but I can easily fix that by having `var str = string + ", a: b";`. Thank you!!!

Comment: Ops... sorry. Fixed the bug and updated the code and the fiddle in the answer. If you find any of the answers useful, please don't forget to accept one. Thanks.

Comment: Ooh! This new update is very useful. I'm unsure about which answer to accept, but I have to admit that yours is ultimately better, thank you very much!

Comment: Accept Redu 'so answer. It's much better than mine.  I just upgraded it. But I accept an upvote :)

Comment: Hey, having done some tests I've discovered that your code stops parsing when it encounters a ".", so I'll have to accept the other solution, sorry

Comment: No problem. I already told you Rude's solution is much better than mine and deserves it. Yet, that's not true, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/gnLk6fdd/15/
I introduced points in some fields and the code completed fine. If you can show me the string where it failed I can correct it.

Comment: My bad. I appear to have been using the old version of your formula.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a regex should do the job. Here is the explanation

```
(desc|sender|se-status|action|target|ta-status|status-apply|lore)(?=:):\s?([^:]+)(?=(,\ssender|,\sse-status|,\saction|,\starget|,\sta-status|,\sstatus-apply|,\slore|$))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P4_dErGZybq3mpjd)

You can check the accompanying JS code and it's result below;

```js
var   r = /(desc|sender|se-status|action|target|ta-status|status-apply|lore)(?=:):\s?([^:]+)(?=(,\ssender|,\sse-status|,\saction|,\starget|,\sta-status|,\sstatus-apply|,\slore|$))/g,
    str = "desc: random text string, sender: James, se-status: red, action: runs, target: John, ta-status: blue, status-apply: red, lore: lore ipsum dolor sit amet",
dataObj = {},
  match = [];
while(match[match.length] = r.exec(str));
match.length--;
dataObj = match.reduce((p,c) => (p[c[1]] = c[2],p),{});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(dataObj,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question but here is one way to turn that string into an object:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/retusu/4/edit?js,console)

```
var s = " desc: random text string, sender: James, se-status: red, action: runs, target: John, ta-status: blue, status-apply: red, lore: lore ipsum dolor sit amet";

var tuples = s.split(',').map(function(a){
  return a.split(':');
}).map(function(b) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[b[0].substring(1)] = b[1].substring(1);
    return obj;
});

var obj = Object.assign.apply({}, tuples);
```

- split by `','` to get pairs, then split each pair by `':'` to get an array of tuples
- map the array of tuples to make objects
- assign all those objects to a new new empty object

now `obj.sender` is equal to 'James'

Comment: This also works perfectly, assuming none of the strings contain a comma. I don't suppose you'd know how to go about averting that error? Thank you very much for your time so far.